# Importing CSV into database, insert without truncating table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code here please, which permits me to import data from a csv file into a database, now what this does is truncating the table before then inserting, I've tried to remove the truncate table before but then it wouldn't pass the data. I mean how can I modify this code here? I need it just to insert the data, without emptying the current table!

Thanks..

```
$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE imovo"; //empty the table of its current records
mysql_query($deleterecords);

//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="INSERT into imovo(date,time,location,rbpos_id,mobile_number) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";

    //view upload form
}else {


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"i've tried to remove the truncate table before but then it wouldn't pass the data."

Maybe because you have **unique index** and try insert duplicate record.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought, your table has an unique column ... so if you don't truncate the table you can't INSERT a Record which exists....

So what you have to do:

1. Check if Record exists

1a) If true ... use UPDATE

1b) if false .. use INSERT

1. Also Check if a Record isn't anymore in your CSV then you have to use DELETE

...

So you see, it is not really simple to handle all existing records

Answer (score 0):

The file you upload is it containing some of the previously uploaded data? 
If this is the case and you know it you can use

```
INSERT IGNORE into `imovo`
```

or if you want to replace some of duplicated rows do REPLACE

```
REPLACE into `imovo`
```

this will replace duplicated rows depending on PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html